# Magento update images from DB source (Direct Query ?)

Tags: php, sql, magento

I have in magento the following code that convert the first page of PDF file (donwloadable product file) and send this first page to an specific place

```
  public function convertPDF(){

    $_prodId  = $this->getProduct()->getId();
    $_proFile =$this->getLinkFile();

    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    if ($product->getTypeId() == 'downloadable') {
        $table = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link');
        $collection = $table->getCollection()->addProductToFilter($product->getId());
        foreach ($collection as $downloadable){
            $linkFile = $downloadable->getLinkFile();
            break;
        }
        $_proFile  = $linkFile;
    }


    $path= '/files/links';
    $pathout= '/product/small/';



     exec('convert '.$path.$_proFile.'[0] '.$pathout.$_prodId.'.jpg');

    }
```

now , i want to take this image and set as small image , i know that small image are stored in 
catalog_product_entity_varchar with attribute id= 86

[image: Table]

my question its how can i update the table setting the result of the function in that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by adding

```
  $conn  = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$sql = "update catalog_product_entity_varchar
set value = ".$_prodId."
where entity_id = ".$_prodId."
and attribute_id  = 86 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```